# Get element by index, [n]

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

I'm using PHPQuery to read some content from HTML, I'm unable to get the element by it's index using the square bracket notation.

See this simple example:

```
$html = '<div><table id="theTable"><tr><td>FIRST TD</td><td>SECOND TD</td><td>THIRD TD</td></tr></table></div>';

$pq = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);

$table = $pq->find('#theTable');
$tds = $table->find('td');

echo "GETTING BY INDEX:\n\n";
echo '$tds[1] = ' . $tds[1];

echo "\n\n\n";

echo "GETTING IN FOREACH:\n\n";
foreach($tds as $key => $td){
    echo '$tds[' . $key . '] = ' . pq($td) . "\n";
}
```

The output of this is:

> GETTING BY INDEX:
>
> $tds[1] =
>
> GETTING IN FOREACH:
>
> $tds[0] = FIRST TD
>
> $tds[1] = SECOND TD
>
> $tds[2] = THIRD TD

I would have expected that I can get the contents of `$tds[1]` using square brackets, but seems not. **How can I get it by index?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer just after posting the question. Instead of square brackets you need to use `eq(n)`:

```
echo '$tds[1] = ' . $tds->eq(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a `var_dump($tds)`, it'll tell you whats exactly inside the tds. Maybe those keys are actually strings and you should use:

```
echo "GETTING BY INDEX:\n\n";
echo '$tds['1'] = ' . $tds['1'];
```

Edit: Also, on your foreach you're using pq(), maybe you should use this

```
echo "GETTING BY INDEX:\n\n";
echo '$tds[1] = ' . pq($tds[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work, the index isn't a string. And `var_dump` prints the whole massive dom tree, it doesn't have indexes.

Comment: Are you sure there's no more code in between your two tests? Maybe you're assigning something different to the `$tds` variable. Edit: Nevermind, I saw your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
echo '$tds[1] = ' . $tds['1'];
```